# Haw can I take snapshots from a live stream in command line?

Tags: software-recommendation, snapshot

I have a security camera and I would like to take snapshots each 5-10 minutes using cron jobs, but I could fined any command line tools,

I tried the following:

```
avconv -i rtsp://ip:554/h264_2 -r 1 -s WxH -f image2 foo.jpeg
```

but the avconc doesn't support RTP/RTSP

```
[NULL @ 0x139d940] Interleaved RTP mode is not supported yet.Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
```

Comment: What's the model number of your camera?

Comment: LevelOne FCS-4041, using vlc I can view the video, I also wrote a program in python, to control the camera, here I can take snapshot, but in this case I need GUI, but I would like to take snapshot on a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** I have absolutely no way of testing this. Mad props to "Ranger", the author of [this code](https://forum.ubnt.com/showpost.php?s=26470c8ca038f1c0b3c9d3adf48a6aac&p=262356&postcount=1).

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 2 -i rtsp://ip:554/h264_2 -y -f image2 -sameq -t 5 foo.jpeg
```

---

Here's a simple script named, for instance, `cam-capture.sh`, that captures an image and names it according to the date and time.

```
#!/bin/sh
export DATETIME=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
export DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
export MONT=`date +%Y%m`
mkdir -p /path/to/output/$MONT/$DATE

ffmpeg -ss 2 -i rtsp://ip:554/h264_2 -y -f image2 -sameq -t 5 /path/to/output/$MONT/$DATE/$DATETIME.jpeg
```

---

Add the following entry to your crontab to execute the script every five minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * sh /path/to/cam-capture.sh
```

---

> Again, all credit for this goes to "[Ranger](https://forum.ubnt.com/showpost.php?s=26470c8ca038f1c0b3c9d3adf48a6aac&p=262356&postcount=1)" for this.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me: Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
[buffer @ 0x1a57e80] Buffering several frames is not supported. Please consume all available frames before adding a new one.
    Last message repeated 79 times   -0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s    
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 Lsize=      -0kB time=10000000000.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -inf%

Comment: Try again, with the revised command

Comment: This worked for me (my ffmpeg version is 2.2): `ffmpeg -ss 2 -i rtsp://ip:554/h264_2 -y -f image2 -qscale 0 -frames 1 /path/to/output/$MONT/$DATE/$DATETIME.jpeg`